BigQuery Error: Field name "NIVEL" is not supported by the current character map. Please change your field name or use character map V2
I am loading a CSV in BigQuery and since today it is giving me the error:
'Field name '"LEVEL"' is not supported by the current character map. Please change your field name or use character map V2 to let the system modify the field names.'
LOAD DATA OVERWRITE `green-gearbox-217510.DATA.INVERSION`
FROM FILES ( format = 'CSV' ,uris = ['gs://landing/INVERSIONES.csv']);

I have even tried it with a file that I used 4 weeks ago, and where it did not fail before, it is now failing with the same message. It's as if BigQuery has made changes to your environment.
The SQL I use is not very scientific, the schema automatically detects it because each CSV field is well defined:
"NIVEL","SECTOR","ENTIDAD","CODIGO_UNICO","CODIGO_SNIP","NOMBRE_INVERSION","NOMBRE_OPMI","NOMBRE_UF","NOMBRE_UEI","SEC_EJEC","NOMBRE_UEP","ESTADO","SITUACION","MONTO_VIABLE","COSTO_ACTUALIZADO","CTRL_CONCURR","ALTERNATIVA","FECHA_REGISTRO","FECHA_VIABILIDAD","FUNCION","PROGRAMA","SUBPROGRAMA","MARCO","TIPO_INVERSION","DES_MODALIDAD","REGISTRADO_PMI","PMI_AÑO_1","PMI_AÑO_2","PMI_AÑO_3","PMI_AÑO_4","EXPEDIENTE_TECNICO","INFORME_CIERRE","TIENE_F9","FEC_REG_F9","ETAPA_F9","PRIMER_DEVENGADO","ULTIMO_DEVENGADO","DEVEN_ACUMUL_AÑO_ANT","DEV_AÑO_ACTUAL","PIA_AÑO_ACTUAL","PIM_AÑO_ACTUAL","DEV_ENE_AÑO_VIG","DEV_FEB_AÑO_VIG","DEV_MAR_AÑO_VIG","DEV_ABR_AÑO_VIG","DEV_MAY_AÑO_VIG","DEV_JUN_AÑO_VIG","DEV_JUL_AÑO_VIG","DEV_AGO_AÑO_VIG","DEV_SET_AÑO_VIG","DEV_OCT_AÑO_VIG","DEV_NOV_AÑO_VIG","DEV_DIC_AÑO_VIG","CERTIF_AÑO_ACTUAL","COMPROM_ANUAL_AÑO_ACTUAL","SALDO_EJECUTAR","TIENE_F8","ETAPA_F8","TIENE_F12B","FECHA_ULT_ACT_F12B","ULT_PERIODO_REG_F12B","TIENE_AVAN_FISICO","AVANCE_FISICO","AVANCE_EJECUCION","ULT_FEC_DECLA_ESTIM","DES_TIPOLOGIA","PROG_ACTUAL_AÑO_ACTUAL","MONTO_VALORIZACION","SANEAMIENTO","DEPARTAMENTO","PROVINCIA","DISTRITO","UBIGEO","LATITUD","LONGITUD","FEC_INI_EJECUCION","FEC_FIN_EJECUCION","FEC_INI_EJEC_FISICA","FEC_FIN_EJEC_FISICA","BENEFICIARIO","MONTO_ET_F8","AÑO_PROCESO" "GL","GOBIERNOS LOCALES","MUNICIPALIDAD DISTRITAL DE ABELARDO PARDO LEZAMETA","2483132","2483132","CREACION DE PISTAS Y VEREDAS DEL JR. BOLOGNESI Y DE LA CALLE EL OLVIDO DE LA LOCALIDAD DE LLACLLA DEL DISTRITO DE ABELARDO PARDO LEZAMETA - PROVINCIA DE BOLOGNESI - DEPARTAMENTO DE ANCASH","OPMI DE LA MUNICIPALIDAD DISTRITAL DE ABELARDO PARDO LEZAMETA","UF DE LA MUNICIPALIDAD DISTRITAL DE ABELARDO PARDO LEZAMETA","UEI DE LA MUNICIPALIDAD DISTRITAL DE ABELARDO PARDO LEZAMETA","300111","MUNICIPALIDAD DISTRITAL DE ABELARDO PARDO LAZAMETA","ACTIVO","VIABLE","341632.2","227250.62","0.0","Pavimentación con concreto rígido fc210 Kgcm en 112000 m de superficie construcción de veredas de concreto fc175 Kgcm en 18500 m de superficie","2020-02-29 00:00:00","2020-06-26 00:00:00","TRANSPORTE","TRANSPORTE URBANO","VÍAS URBANAS","INVIERTE","PROYECTO DE INVERSION","ADMINISTRACIÓN DIRECTA","SI","83844.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","SI","NO","NO","","","202312","202403","105752.0","89785.4","83844.0","171819","0.0","43633.4","46152.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","119579.74","89785.4","-50320.38","SI","Ejecución física (C)","SI","2024-02-18 21:34:16","","SI","51.44","50.06","2024-01-16 20:25:55","VIAS URBANAS","83844.0","0.0","NO","ANCASH","BOLOGNESI","ABELARDO PARDO LEZAMETA","020502","-10.298550883901298","-77.14807105571111","2020-06-01 00:00:00","2020-08-01 00:00:00","2024-01-11 00:00:00","2024-03-11 00:00:00","242","227250.62","2024" "GL","GOBIERNOS LOCALES","MANCOMUNIDAD MUNICIPAL VALLE DE LAS CATARATAS -BONGARÁ REGION AMAZONAS","2590550","2590550","CONSTRUCCION DE PLANTA DE VALORIZACION ADQUISICION DE VOLQUETE, CONTENEDOR Y MESA CON FAJA TRANSPORTADORA ADEMÁS DE OTROS ACTIVOS EN EL(LA) MANCOMUNIDAD MUNICIPAL VALLE DE LAS CATARATAS  DISTRITO DE SAN CARLOS, PROVINCIA BONGARA, DEPARTAMENTO AMAZONAS","","MANCOMUNIDAD MUNICIPAL VALLE DE LAS CATARATAS -BONGARÁ REGION AMAZONAS","","300036","MUNICIPALIDAD DISTRITAL DE SAN CARLOS","ACTIVO","APROBADO","1492590.0","1492590.0","0.0","","2023-04-20 00:00:00","2023-04-20 00:00:00","AMBIENTE","GESTIÓN INTEGRAL DE LA CALIDAD AMBIENTAL","GESTIÓN DE LOS RESIDUOS SÓLIDOS","INVIERTE","INVERSIONES IOARR","ADMINISTRACIÓN INDIRECTA - POR CONTRATA-","SI","0.0","10000.0","10000.0","1452090.0","NO","NO","NO","","","202305","202305","20500.0","0.0","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","1472090.0","NO","","NO","","","NO","","","","GESTIÓN INTEGRAL DE LOS RESIDUOS SÓLIDOS MUNICIPALES","","","NO","AMAZONAS","BONGARA","SAN CARLOS","010309","-5.953143348296967","-77.95239870756089","","","","","","","2024"

I don't understand what is happening in BigQuery.
Any suggestions to resolve this error?

I encountered a similar issue in the last few weeks. My Cloud Function that loaded CSV data (with autodetection) stopped working with the same error for a column name that had spaces in it (previously it converted it to underscores without any issue).
After going down a rabbit hole I found this Google Form that you have to fill out to gain access to "Load job with flexible column name preview access (CSV & Parquet only)".
The documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#flexible-column-names:~:text=Loading%20CSV%20data,returning%20an%20error.
The form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeVgijbPY9ruMX_Ujkngzv-1AX12JDbnyrE20q4LEk9n76eBQ/viewform
I just asked for the activation so I cannot comment on whether this actually resolves the issue, but it was the only lead I could find.

The column options aren't listed consistently across the various bits of documentation, but I finally found the documentation for this one.
LOAD DATA OVERWRITE `green-gearbox-217510.DATA.INVERSION`
FROM FILES (
    format = 'CSV',
    uris = ['gs://landing/INVERSIONES.csv'],
    column_name_character_map = 'V2'
);

Both 'V1' ("Column names can only contain standard column name characters. Unsupported characters are replaced with underscores.") and 'V2' ("Enables flexible column names. Unsupported characters are replaced with underscores. This is the recommended setting, except in use cases with external tables.") worked for my files.

Try to change the column name in the table
eg: if column name in the csv file is "first_name:WString(14)" change it to "first_name"

Expand the Advanced options menu when creating the table and change the Column name character map to V2. This allows parentheses to be used in column names. If you don't do this and just leave the default character map, the table will fail to be created because BigQuery will not recognize parentheses in the column names as valid characters.
